# Formula returning Column A value for row containing MIN value of a range. If two equal values then return the smaller one

Tags: excel, indexing

```
column  A   B
14-Jan-00   14
11-Jan-00   11
8-Jan-00    1
8-Jan-00    2
8-Jan-00    4
0
```

I have used the following formula

```
=INDEX(E:E,MAX((D4:D33=(MIN(IF(D4:D33>0,D4:D33,9E+99))))*ROW(D4:D33)))
```

But it returns number 4, Max value of column B for min value in column A (Excluding 0). I need the min value from column B for min value in column A (excluding 0)

I would appreciate if anyone can advise on how to correct this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is a little convoluted, to get the minimum of the minimum date that is not 0 this array formula will work:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$6=MIN(IF(A1:A6<>0,A1:A6)),B1:B6))
```

Being and array formula this needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

**OR**

You can use this array formula that does not require the use of CSE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$6/($A$1:$A$6=AGGREGATE(15,6,A1:A6/(A1:A6<>0),1)),1)
```

It would get entered as a normal formula.

[image]

Comment: @MSch please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the person who posed the question can do.